# How to check time automatically?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am writing a backup process.

> Step1: User selects 3 times (Tuesday 1am,3am,10am or Everyday 1am,3am,10am)
>
> Step 2: The application should check the time settings and start the backup process automatically.

Is it possible to start the backup process if the application is not running?

Comment: check this out on how to interact with windows task scheduler: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx

Comment: how are you going to limit it to application not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your client/user is using Windows operating system then you can use Windows Task Scheduler to do the job. To schedule the job programmatically see [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx) and [this post](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2004/08/Interfacing-the-Windows-Task-Scheduler.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use Windows Schedule ?

Comment: @bryanmac this is exactly what Windows Task Scheduler does! other wise using a timer would solve hist problem!

Comment: I read it as a process/tool written that backs up his data (that scheduler would run) and another process/application that is using his data - schedule and only backup if app not running.  How would task scheduler protect against that?  You would need a system wide mutex.  Perhaps that's not what he meant at all  maybe he meant schedule and don't overlap ...

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use the Windows Task Scheduler. Windows will take care of running your application.

Comment: can i use this for a ASP.Net web site??

Comment: what do you mean asp.net web site? if you mean to call any specific page or web service, then you need to create a simple windows application to call the page / web service once the task scheduler runs.

Comment: The Scheduler runs executables. You can create a small EXE or a PowerShell script that will access your ASP.NET website and trigger whatever action you want.

Comment: @zmbq i want to backup the database on my server using Windows Task Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

IMO you can use Windows Scheduler, that is the best. and Also do care of TimeZones :P :P

here are the links which may help you.

[Task Scheduler](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/scheduler.aspx)